# Javascript Timer Triggers only the first time

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to trigger a function 3 seconds after a click of a button. The code is fairly simple :

```
button.onclick = setTimeout(yup,3000);
```

The function name is yup. The first time I click the button, the function occurs, but if I click it again, nothing happens. What am I missing?

Comment: A complete example would be better. So far there is no issue :)

Comment: Here's a fiddle with all the code: https://jsfiddle.net/1at5Le5n/

Comment: @BulentVural Function basically changes height, width, shape and location of the button. Works fine without the timer.

Answer (score 2):

You are setting the return value of setTimeout as a click handler.

```
button.onclick = function() {
    setTimeout(yup, 3000);
}
```

Comment: Thanks that did it!